# iBATIS.NET WebSessionStore throwing an exception

Tags: c#, ibatis.net

I have a web app that uses the iBATIS.NET library.

The DAO is configured by using an XmlDocument, so the code is very similar to what they show in the documentation:

```
XmlDocument anXmlDoc = someSupportClass.GetDynamicXmlDocument();
DomDaoManagerBuilder builder = new DomDaoManagerBuilder();
builder.Configure(anXmlDoc);
```

The documentation says right below that:

> The DaoManager instance that is built from a dao.config file is aware
>   of all of the contexts contained within the configuration file. The
>   context basically bundles DAO implementations together with a session
>   handler. The DaoManager knows which DAOs and session handler belong to
>   which context. When you request a DAO instance from the DaoManager,
>   the proper session handler will be provided with it. Therefore, there
>   is no need to access the context or session handler directly. Your DAO
>   knows how it works.

This does not appear to be true. In a threaded process, the following exception is thrown randomly:

> WebSessionStore: Could not obtain reference to HttpContext    at
>   IBatisNet.DataAccess.SessionStore.WebSessionStore.ObtainSessionContext()
>   at
>   IBatisNet.DataAccess.SessionStore.WebSessionStore.get_LocalSession()
>   at IBatisNet.DataAccess.DaoManager.IsDaoSessionStarted()    at
>   IBatisNet.DataAccess.Configuration.DaoProxy.Intercept(IInvocation
>   invocation, Object[] arguments)

The application may run fine for days or even months at a time, but every once in awhile this exception is thrown. The only solution I can find mentioned anywhere is to swap out the SessionStore for a `HybridWebThreadSessionStore` ([mentioned here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IBATISNET-279)).

As the documentation says above, this shouldn't be necessary. If I wanted to force it though, how would I go about overriding the SessionStore created by the `DomDaoManagerBuilder`?

Comment: The first answer on this thread worked for me: http://ibatis.10938.n7.nabble.com/Help-in-MultiThreads-td24432.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by a race condition in the iBatis.NET framework when the application starts up. If a call to the database is made on the main thread before a call to the database is made on a separate thread, then the separate threads will raise the error since they don't have an HttpContext stored in the SessionStore.

Basically it went `Startup -> db call on main thread -> db call on separate thread`

When it should have been `Startup -> db call on separate thread -> db call on main thread`

Basically I just changed the order in which events fire to make sure the db call on the thread is called at least once before anything on the main thread happens.

[This post describes the same problem](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ibatis-user-cs/200608.mbox/%3C891edd880608261554q3dda9de6jc6fe1b4dbd14d731@mail.gmail.com%3E)

> THE SETUP
>
> In my Global.asax, I kick-start a background process using the Timer
>   class.  This Timer class uses a delgate DoTimerBasedStuff() which is
>   called periodically. The DoTimerBasedStuff() method accesses two
>   different databases, MySQL and SQL Server.  Both are setup properly
>   using their MySQLMapper and SQLServerMapper classes.
>
> Aside from a couple of these background threads, the application also
>   has a web front which accesses both databases using typical .aspx
>   pages and classes inherited from Page.  Nothing fancy.
>
> THE PROBLEM
>
> If the application is started by going to index.aspx using a browser
>   (this page doesn't do any db stuff but triggers Global.asax) and no
>   other actions are taken until the first call of DoTimerBasedStuff()
>   all is well and both the background process and the web users are
>   fine.  IBatis does everything right.
>
> BUT if I start the application by going to index.aspx and then
>   immediately do some work via the web which accesses a database (before
>   DoTimerBasedStuff() is executed), the DoTimerBasedStuff() method has
>   trouble accessing the HttpContext and gives the following error:
>
> Exception: WebSessionStore: Could not obtain reference to HttpContext
>     at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SessionStore.WebSessionStore.ObtainSessionContext()
>     at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SessionStore.WebSessionStore.get_LocalSession()
>     at IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapper.QueryForObject(String
>     ...

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because you run ibatis in different threads.
You can make use of a new instance of HybridWebThreadSessionStore just before making a query to the database.

```
var map = new Hashtable
{
   { "FilterA", "MyFilter" }
};
SqlMap.SessionStore = new HybridWebThreadSessionStore(SqlMap.Id);
var listadoJobs = SqlMap.QueryForList<EventoJob>(SbsIbatisConstantes.ListarJobs, map).ToList();
```

You can check this reference [Here](https://github.com/beginor/iBATIS_2010/blob/master/IBatisNet.DataMapper/SessionStore/HybridWebThreadSessionStore.cs)

That worked for me.